# display a value in the matlab console

Tags: matlab

```
function c =  makecode(s, codeword)
global CODE;
if(length(s) == 1)

    CODE{s(1)} = codeword;


else

    makecode(s{1}, [codeword 1]);
    display(s{1})
    makecode(s{2}, [codeword 0]);
    display(s{2})


end
 c= CODE;
end
```

This function is called from another .m file. But I don't see anything printed on the console. Am I doing it wrong?
This is how it's called.

```
sig = [1,2,3];
p = [0.6 0.3 0.1];
global CODE

s = cell(length(p),1);
s = {1,2,3};
[p, i] = sort(p);
p(2) = p(1) + p(2);
p(1) = [];
s = s(i);
s{2} = {s{1}, s{2}};
s(1) = [];

makecode(s,[])
```

Comment: This code look fine. It prints `s` in the command window as it would be printed by just writing `s` without a semicolon. Maybe the function gets `returned` in the part above the line `display(s)`. To determine this, we actually need to see this code.

Comment: How do you call the function (exact inputs)? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Matt , I added that code too,

Comment: works for me, I see an output

Comment: I get `ans = 3`, `ans = 2 ;  [3]    [2]` and `ans =  1`

Comment: ans = 

    [0]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]  
I get only above output. I'm using matlab R2013a.

Comment: I get the `[1x2 double]` stuff too... but I'm going to write an answer.

Comment: @Matt - The formatting must have changed in R2015a.  I get the outputs to be truncated like Anna.

Comment: @rayryeng Interesting that the output gets truncated. I would like to replicate this issue. I don't quite understand what the OP wants, maybe this causes confusion here. The output of `makecode` or the temporary values of the cells of `s` inside the function?

Comment: @Matt - Inside `makecode`, the OP Is displaying several things... I just removed all of those `display` statements.  The output is ultimately coming from the call to `makecode`.  No variable is assigned to this call and so it should be stored in `ans`.  If you just did `ans` and pushed ENTER in the command prompt, you get `ans = [0] [1x2 double] [1x2 double]`... at least on my end.  You can remove this by calling `celldisp(ans)`.  My guess is that the OP wants to see what's inside the cell, rather than seeing the `[1x2 double]` stuff... and so using `celldisp` should solve the problem.

Comment: @Matt - BTW, totally agree with the problem statement... it's a bit odd.

Comment: Anna Fernando, please clarify what exactly should be printed. Edit your answer, so we can see an example of the expected result. @rayryeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`celldisp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html) to display the contents of a cell array.  Don't use `display`.  First, assign the output of `makecode` to something... call it `out`:

```
out = makecode(s,[]);
```

After, use `celldisp` on this:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

     0



out{2} =

     1     0



out{3} =

     1     1
```

---

To be self-contained, this is the output I currently get when I run the above code untouched.  I'm on MATLAB R2014a (64-bit) on Windows 7 x64 Professional:

```
ans =

     3


ans =

     2

    [3]    [2]


ans =

     1


ans = 

    [0]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

`ans` contains the most current state of what is to be displayed.... so if you just did a `celldisp` on `ans`, we get:

```
>> celldisp(ans)

ans{1} =

     0



ans{2} =

     1     0



ans{3} =

     1     1
```

Comment: I meant the OP should give an example, that's why I mentioned you at the end of the comment... He really needs to be clear what he wants... Your answer is correct if he wants the result of `makecode`. BTW, R2014b, OSX10.10 gives the same result.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you very much. That's what I really wanted.

Comment: @AnnaFernando Perfect, so +1 from my side.